# Explicit computation of Gromov-WItten invariants

Tags: reference-request, gromov-witten-theory, equivariant-cohomology

After studying some foundation of Gromow-Witten invariants, I now would like to see an explicit computation. I heard that one should first take a look at the total space of $\mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus2}$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$ or the total space of the canonical bundle of Fano surface (local Calabi-Yau). They can be worked out very explicitly via equivariant cohomology and localization. (Or there may be more tractable examples)

Could someone kindly suggest a paper or lecture note where I can start learning these examples and technique? Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

*Gromov-Witten classes, quantum cohomology, and enumerative geometry* (by Kontsevich & Manin)

*J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology* (by McDuff & Salamon)

*A tutorial on quantum cohomology* (by Givental)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Chris. The Givental's paper looks very good with Fano examples. I am now more interested in CY examples (I should have emphasize this point in my question). I don't have the first two books at hand now and cannot say anything, but if my memory serves they don't have much concrete examples but theories. Anyways, I appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No they have examples. (and you can quickly download them on the internet)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is among the lines of what you're looking for.

http://mat.uab.es/~kock/invitation.html

The exercises are a very valuable part of this book, for it contains a handful of nice exercises.

As for lecture notes, Renzo Cavalieri has some nice notes you might find helpful. He knows a good deal localization.

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/